# Partial fraction method in Integration

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

My question is can we proceed with the method without even factorising the denominator.
For eg take a question.
$$\int \frac{2x-3}{(x^2-1)(2x+3)}dx$$
Can we write directly
$$\frac{2x-3}{(x^2-1)(2x+3)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2-1}+\frac{C}{2x-3}$$
without simplifying denominator term $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)$?

Comment: What you wrote is OK.  But if possible we avoid that, because integrating $A/(x-1)$ and $B/(x+1)$ is easier than integrating $(Ax+B)/(x^2-1)$.  Later, you may go even further: avoid $(Ax+b)/(x^2+1)$ by factoring this denominator using complex numbers $(x+i)(x-i)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem in this; it's just a matter of choice. **HOWEVER**, if you resolve the integrand as
$$\frac{2x-3}{(x^2-1)(2x+3)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2-1}+\frac{C}{2x-3}$$
then how would you go about integrating $(Ax+B)/(x^2-1)$?

Unless you are lucky that $B=0$, (in the above case you get $B=1$), in all other cases, you will have no choice but again resolving it into two more fractions, so why not do it directly?

---

**Edit**

Suppose we get $A=5$ and $B=0$ in the above one, then integrating is trivial.
$$\int \frac{5x}{x^2-1}\ dx=\int\frac 5 2 \frac{2x}{x^2-1}\ dx$$
$$ = \frac{5}{2}\ln |x^2-1|$$
However, say we get $B=1$, then how would you solve
$$\int\frac{5x+1}{x^2-1}$$
You have no other choice but to use partial fraction decomposition.

Hope this is clear :)

Comment: How is B=1in the above case

Comment: Just solve the equation you have!

Comment: Please wait I am uploading

Comment: I'm not sure, because I did some mental calculations ; but I'm for sure, that $B\neq0$ in this case.

Comment: Yeah that is not zero

Comment: sir please wait

Comment: I edited something, see that too!

Comment: ∫5x/x²-1 and ∫1/x²-1 and then solve both

Comment: Nah! How would you integrate $1/(x^2-1)$? Just tell me.

Comment: isn't there a formula that ∫dx/x²-a² =(1/2a) log {(x-a)/(x+a)}

Comment: That formula is derived from partial fraction decomposition; back to my point.

Comment: Okay then . Now in this case we can actually do that directly alright.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, consider marking it as accepted so that it doesn't bother users, looking for unanswered questions.